# Python not found module named 'pip'

Tags: python, pip

I've get a error named : `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'`

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):   File
 "D:\obj\windows-release\37win32_Release\msi_python\zip_win32\runpy.py",
 line 193, in _run_module_as_main   File
 "D:\obj\windows-release\37win32_Release\msi_python\zip_win32\runpy.py",
 line 85, in _run_code   File "D:\Python\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py",
 line 4, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the differing paths in the traceback, you're mixing and matching multiple installations of Python (one in `D:\obj\windows-release\37win32_Release\msi_python` maybe, the other in `D:\Python`).

My educated guess is you're running the interpreter in `D:\obj\windows-release\37win32_Release\msi_python` using a script from `D:\Python\Scripts`; while the `D:\Python` installation might have the actual `pip` library, the other installation doesn't seem to.

You'll need to sort out why or how you're running multiple Python interpreters, then either install `pip` in all of them (https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) or clean up things so you're only running one interpreter.